# How to get value of dynamically created dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dropdown

I instantiate a list of users in my DOM and then tie their name to the dropdown list. So they are not created until page load. I'm having trouble trying to target the `<option>` tag and access it's value.

**JS DOM Function**

```
  let userDropDownList = userInstantiation.reduce((usersHTML, user) => {
    usersHTML += `<option class="nav__div__one__dropdown__choice" value="${user.id}">${user.name}</option>`
    return usersHTML;
  }, '')
  navDivDropdown.innerHTML = userDropDownList
}
```

I've tried to loop through the `<option>` tags but I'm returning empty an array. My wrapper in my `index.html` is `<select class="nav__div__one__dropdown" name="users"></select>`

I'm attempting to get the value so that I can tye the user.id to the User instance and access those class methods. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `onchange` event on the select input like so:

```
<select onchange="changed(this)"></select>

function changed(option){
 console.log(option.value);
}
```

Here is a working snippet

```js
let userInstantiation = [{id: 1, name: 'user1'},{id: 2, name: 'user2'}];
let userDropDownList = userInstantiation.reduce((usersHTML, user) =>
    usersHTML += 
    `<option class="nav__div__one__dropdown__choice" value="${user.id}">${user.name}</option>`
  , '')
  document.querySelector(".nav__div__one__dropdown").innerHTML = userDropDownList;
  
function changed(option){
 console.log(option.value);
}
```

```html
<select class="nav__div__one__dropdown" onchange="changed(this)" name="users"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you would go about it this way

```
document.querySelector('nav__div__one__dropdown').addEventListner('change',(e)=>{
  const userId=e.target.value; 
  //here do your user tying logic 
})
```